# How to determine actual Signal-R message size

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr

I have a component library, one of its functionalyty is to pass large file from JS to c# code. I split the file into chunks, but I need to know what chunk size should be used.

Default message size is 32 kb, but user can change it in theirs app:

```
services.AddSignalR(o => {
   o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = long.MaxValue;
});
```

How can I determine the message size in my library code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Server, Inject `IOptions<HubOptions> options` into a service or controller.

```
var maximumReceiveMessageSize = options.Value.MaximumReceiveMessageSize;
```

Comment: Use this code to inject: `@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubOptions> Options`

Comment: @EugeneMaksimov Yes that works for `.razor` pages however in a service it would be just a parameter of the services constructor.